# AngularJS: fetch json from server using AJAX

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax

I am looking at this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp). And I have such code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SPA book_store</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/book_store/rest/books_json/get")
                .then(function(response) {
                    $scope.books = response.data;
                });
    });
</script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<input id="filter_input" type="text" ng-model="nameText"/>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="book in books | filter:nameText | orderBy:'name'">
        {{book.name}} - {{book.price}}
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

`http://localhost:8080/book_store/rest/books_json/get` is returning following `json`:

```
[  
   {  
      "book_id":1,
      "name":"Book1",
      "bought":false,
      "genre":"MR",
      "price":20,
      "users":[  

      ],
      "author":{  
         "author_id":1,
         "name":"Gogol",
         "books":[  

         ]
      }
   },
//...
]
```

But I see in a browser networking that request wasn't fire. What have I done wrong?

Comment: So you mean in your network tab there isn't any request to `http://localhost:8080/book_store/rest/books_json/get` ? Or doesn't it return anything? Or doesn't it display anything?

Comment: Check your console tab in developer tools of your browser, there must be some error.

Comment: @devqon, yes, I mean exactly this

Comment: Copied and pasted your code in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czo6yxuq/), and it does the request

Comment: I have exception in the browser console: `angular.js:13920Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/areq?p0=myCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined`

Comment: You have your `ng-app` defined twice, remove one of them (probably the one on the `<html>` tag)

Comment: Also, if you use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js`, your errors will be more descriptive

Comment: Thanks guys, It was my first acquaintance with AngularJS and yours suggestions were very helpful. Apart of `ng-app=""` issue, I had to add header on server side `httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` It solved problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `ng-app=""` from the html tag or provide the module name `ng-app="MyApp"`.

Also remove one of the ng-app directives either from the the body tag or the html tag.

It is good practice to user the ng-app directive on the HTML tag if you are using just one angular app.